# OnClickListener in SurfaceView Android

Tags: java, android, surfaceview

I'm trying to add an Onclicklistener to my SurfaceView. I've put two png images in a loop that looks like a bird flapping its wings. I want a sound to be played when the user clicks on the bird but currently, nothing is happening. I'm not really sure how I would implement soundpool yet but for now, I've just added a toast message just to see if the onClick works. Unfortunately, nothing happens when I click on the bird in the emulator.

Any help on how to implement an on-click listener and soundpool to my surfaceView is much appreciated!

```
public class PlayActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

surfaceView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    view = new surfaceView(this);
    setContentView(view);


}

public class surfaceView extends SurfaceView implements View.OnClickListener {

    public surfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        new Anim().start();

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Bird Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private class Anim extends Thread {
        int counter = 0;


        @Override
        public void run() {
            long last_updated_time = 0;
            long delay = 250;
            int[] img_ids = {
                    R.drawable.bird1,
                    R.drawable.bird2
            };



            while (true) {
                boolean playing = true;
                if (playing) {
                    long current_time = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    if (current_time > last_updated_time + delay) {
                        if (counter >= 2) {
                            counter = 0;


                        }
                        draw(img_ids[counter]);
                        last_updated_time = current_time;
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void draw (int img_ids) {
            SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getContext().getResources(),
                        img_ids);
                Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,(int)(bitmap.getWidth()*0.2), (int)(bitmap.getHeight()*0.2), true);
                canvas.drawBitmap(resized, 100, 100, paint);
                holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);


            }

        }


        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you haven't set an `OnClickListener` anywhere. You can do so with [`View.setOnClickListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)).

Comment: I have added implements View.OnClickListener to the class surfaceview, I only get the option of View.OnClickListener not the SetOnClickListener.

Comment: @Henry is right, you need to attach the View.setOnClickListener with a view that you want to be clicked, implementing Listener will not work here, 
Either in the SurfaceView you have to attach the listener to any view
Or in the activity attach Listener to the SurfaceView Inctance